# Finding the Formula for a Curve

Tags: math, curve-fitting

Is there a program that will take "response curve" values from me, and provide a formula that approximates the response curve?

It would be cool if such a program would take a numeric "percent correct" (perhaps with a standard deviation) so that it returns simplified formulas when laxity is permissable, and more precise (viz. complex) formulas when the curve needs to be approximated closely.

My interest is to play with the response curve values and "laxity" factor, until such a tool spits out a curve-fit formula simple enough that I know it will be high performance during machine computations.

Comment: I just now noticed that MS Excel has this ability, at least partially: http://phoenix.phys.clemson.edu/tutorials/excel/graph.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check our [Eureqa](http://ccsl.mae.cornell.edu/eureqa), a free (as in beer) utility from Cornell University.

What's particularly interesting about Eureqa is that it uses genetic algorithms to fit the input curve you specify, and you can say what functions to allow or not in the fit.  So if you wanted to stay away from sine and cosine, for instance, it wouldn't even consider those.  It will also show you the best approximation with the fewest steps, and the most accurate approximation (regardless of steps).  You can also run the fitting tool across multiple networked computers to speed up getting your results.

It's a very interesting tool -- check out their how-to videos.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab, mathematica, octave, maple, numpy, scilab are just six among thousands of programs that will do this.

Comment: I think he's looking for something simpler. If we go that way, might as well take a pen & piece of paper ...

Comment: Unlike pen and paper, these tools all have documented curve fitting functions out of the box.

Comment: And a man who knows has them documented in his memory as well. Still, try to look how many lines it takes you in, I don't know, numpy to load data and to fit a exponential curve.

Answer (score 1):

SigmaPlot - does exactly what you're looking for. Statistics and visualization of data.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sigmaplot.com](http://www.sigmaplot.com/products/sigmaplot/img-sigmaplot/big_pic3.gif))</sub>

Comment: Looks pretty cool, though of course I'll side with a free solution (making Eureqa look rather good).